# dlopen load library correct,but run the program,the result is incorrect

Tags: mysql, c, linux, dlopen, dlsym

I use dlopen, dlsym load library function. When I run the program, I met this problem：

1. use dlopen load function, call the function correct but the result is incorrect
2. don't use dlopen and call the function directly,the result is correct

How can I find the problem?

Example：

```
void *dl_handle = NULL;
char *error = NULL;

/* Open the shared object */
dl_handle = dlopen(pLibraryName, RTLD_LAZY );
if (!dl_handle) 
{
     return -1
}

char* error = NULL;
pFunc = dlsym( dlHandle, "mysql_rollback");
error = dlerror();
if (error != NULL)\
{
    return -1
}
```

Comment: Is your `pFunc` the same prototype with mysql_rollback?

Comment: How are you using pFunc ?